# Take the product of all nonzero elements in each column of a sparse matrix

Tags: matlab, octave, vectorization, sparse-matrix, multiplication

Is there a well-vectorized way to take the product of all the nonzero elements in each column of a sparse matrix in octave (or matlab) (returning a row-vector of products)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd combine `find` with `accumarray`:

```
%# create a random sparse array
s = sprand(4,4,0.6);

%# find the nonzero values
[rowIdx,colIdx,values] = find(s);

%# calculate product
product = accumarray(colIdx,values,[],@prod)
```

---

Some alternatives (that might be less efficient; you may want to profile them)

```
%# simply set the zero-elements to 1, then apply prod
%# may lead to memory issues
s(s==0) = 1;
product = prod(s,1);
```

.

```
%# do "manual" accumarray
[rowIdx,colIdx,values] = find(s);

product = zeros(1,size(s,2));
uCols = unique(colIdx);

for col = uCols(:)'
    product(col) = prod(values(colIdx==col));
end
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about accumarray.  Do you know if there's any way that doesn't involve function passing?

Comment: @dspyz: what do you mean with "function passing"?

Comment: @dspyz Assuming that when you say "avoid function passing" you are referring to the `@prod` argument to `accumarray` - that is how `accumarray` knows which function to apply to the array. It is the typical, intended syntax. Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: Just because it limits the efficiency.  Ideally, I'm looking for an approach that only invokes compiled code.  It's the same reason you would just use sum rather than accumarray(... @sum)

Comment: @dspyz: I have added two additional solutions. They may (or not) be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative approach to solving this, but it may be slower and not quite as precise in the worst-case:

Simply take the log of all the nonzero elements and then sum the columns.  Then take the exp of the resulting vector:

```
function [r] = prodnz(m)
    nzinds = find(m != 0);
    vals = full(m(nzinds));
    vals = log(vals);
    m(nzinds) = vals;
    s = full(sum(m));
    r = exp(s);
endfunction
```